# Who is calling my javascript method?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand what is the "this" referencing inside my method, the method is declared like:

*(corrected as the answers asked for, but still not working)*

```
Myclass = function() {
    this.focused = function() {
        alert("caller = " + this.focused.caller);
    }
}
var obj = new Myclass();
```

and it's showing:

```
this.focused is undefined
```

So, how can I get the caller for this function?

Comment: This is not valid javascript.  A curly bracket cannot immediately follow a function call.

Comment: @Mike Samuel for some reason it works here, I'm using this javascript within a Xul app. The only thing I can't do is show the caller for some function (looks like only for events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was on the event registering, with

```
window.onfocus = self.focused;
```

it was not working, but with

```
var self = this;
window.addEventListener("focus", function() { self.focused(); }, false);
```

it works well..

I just wonder why it also don't work with:

```
var focused = this.focused;
window.addEventListener("focus", function() { focused(); }, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I would debug this is to add a line

console.info(this)

If you are developing with FireBug, it will show you right away what's going on. Who "this" is depends on where it is getting called from - it may be the "window" object.

Comment: "depends on where it is getting called from", it's just what I'm trying to discovery.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var name = arguments.callee.caller.name;
```

Comment: It printed nothing. If I print `arguments.callee.caller` it prints `null`.

Comment: now, from where it's being called, I don't know.. It's what I'm trying to discover.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
obj = new Myclass() {

    this.focused = function() {
        alert("caller = " + Function.caller.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the name of the function itself: http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsfunCaller.htm

Comment: that's what I did, and it prints `this.focused is undefined`

Comment: @Tom Brito that's the end of my knowledge on the subject then, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You must define your object correctly if you are going to get the result you expect.

```
Myclass = function() {
  this.focused=function() {
    alert("caller = " + this.focused.caller);
  };
}
obj = new Myclass();
```

Comment: Its corrected, also with `var obj = new Myclass`, but it still prints an error `this.focused is undefined`